# JavaFX scene builder 2.0 error in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx-2

When I try to set the scene builder home in Netbeans 7.4 and target the /Applications/JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0.app its throwing me an error:

```
Selected location /Applications/JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0.app does not represent a valid JavaFX Scene builder installation.
```

Answer (score 2):

I still get this error with Netbeans 7.4, but I've found a workaround:

Go to the folder where you extracted/installed Scene Builder 2 and rename the executable file to "JavaFX Scene Builder 1.1"

It will now be recognized as a valid Scene Builder directory.

Comment: Note that this won't be fixed in 7.4, they patched it in Netbeans 8 and consider the case closed. See: [https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=238520](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=238520). By the way, thanks for the tip! Linking (`ln`) indeed fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the [bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=220532), they say that the solution is available in 7.3 beta and higher.

**Bug:**

> Selecting the JavaFX scene builder home directory throws following
>   error: " does not represent a valid JavaFX Scene Builder
>   installation."
>
> This seems to caused by the names of the subdirectories inside the
>   Scene Builder's root directory; 'app' and 'runtime' (version 1.1 of
>   Scene Builder). When you change the names of those directories to
>   'bin' and 'lib' respectively, selecting the home directory works (but
>   breaks Scene Builder executable ofcourse).
>
> Only 'workaround' is simply using the Scene Builder outside of
>   Netbeans.
>
> This was tested using Scene Builder 1.1 and NB 7.2 + 7.3beta.

**Solution:**

> Fixed after 7.3 Beta1 and backported to 7.2.1 (now available at
>   netbeans.org).
>
> Either install 7.2.1 or update your 7.2 (you'll get the same set of
>   patches).

**Installation Instructions:**
Please read [these instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/installation_1-1/jsbpub-installation_1-1.htm) to see if you have made any errors while installation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with NB 7.4 and JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0 on Debian.

At the moment I solved it installing JavaFX Scene Builder 1.1

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you must use netbeans version 7.4 and using javafx  scence builder 1.1 .
it works.

Comment: How does it work? Can you please explain in some more detail?

Comment: first off all u have download net-beans 7.4.then download scence builder 1.1 then  install scence builder in c drive. and also check in net-beans. goto tool->option->select java tab->click on javafx tab then check scence builder is automatically set otherwise click on browse and adjust scence builder path.

Comment: I know that. What I mean to ask is **how** does it work? What is it in scence builder 1.1 and net-beans 7.4 that makes it work?

Comment: scence builder is tool in which u develope a design a form.in scence builder u care about two thing. first is to assign a controller to particular stage and set id of all control it is depend upon u in which control is used in application.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0 working within NetBeans 7.4 by just renaming the "JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0.exe" to "JavaFX Scene Builder 1.1.exe". Then follow the instructions for Configuring the Scene Builder Installation Location from here. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/scene-builder-2/work-with-java-ides/sb-with-nb.htm#JSBID108/

Answer (score 0):

SceneBuilder 2 produces FXML compiant with Java 8.

[NetBeans 8](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/) has official support for Java 8, so use SceneBuilder 2 with NetBeans 8+ running on Java 8+.

[Oracle provides an official tutorial on the use of SceneBuilder 2 and NetBeans 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/scene-builder-2/work-with-java-ides/sb-with-nb.htm#JSBID108).  Follow the tutorial to get it to work.

> **Configuring the Scene Builder Installation Location**
>
> If you did not install Scene Builder in the default installation
>   location, use the following steps to let NetBeans IDE be aware of its
>   location:
>
> 1. From the IDE's Main menu, select Tools and choose Options.
>
>    On the Mac OS platform, select NetBeans and choose Preferences from the Main menu.
> 2. In the Options window, click Java and then the JavaFX tab.
> 3. Specify the location of the Scene Builder installation folder and then click OK.