# JavaFX CSS Error ( Property Stylesheets does not exist )

Tags: java, css, intellij-idea, javafx

I have just began building a JavaFX application in IntelliJ using the latest Java7 SDK.

I have built my interface using Oracle Scene Builder, everything runs and displays fine on the preview, but when I try and compile my program I get the following error

```
`Property "stylesheets" does not exist or is read-only`
```

Judging against JavaFX Documentation the line `stylesheets="@MainView.css"` in my FXML does not appear invalid.

Does anybody know why I am getting this error? ( If I remove the link to the stylesheet my program compiles just fine, so the problem lies solely with the stylesheet, I'm stumped! )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I needed to manually link the stylesheet in my start() method as JavaFX7 does not support the stylesheets tag.

To fix this I called the following command in my Start() method

```
root.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("view/MainView.css").toExt‌​ernalForm());
```

Where `root` is the name of my FXMLLoader.

Answer (score 6):

You were creating an FXML in Scene Builder 2 and running in JDK 7. SB 2 "tries to" create Java 8 compatible FXML code. To fix the FXML:

1. Remove the `stylesheets="@MainView.css"` attribute
2. Add `<?import java.net.*?>` in the imports
3. Add the below code at the end of parent pane, after `</children>` (in my case it was before `</AnchorPane>`):

   ```
   <stylesheets>
     <URL value="@MainView.css" />
   </stylesheets>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same error when I was trying to set my own CSS properties in my program. If you are not doing this, you are probably using some class that uses the [CSS library](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/CSS+API+to+support+custom+UI+Controls) introduced in JavaFX 8.

Try to update your JDK to the latest released version [here](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html).

If this still does not work, then somewhere in your application a CSS file is not being read correctly. There is probably some class with JavaFX bean properties that were wrongly mapped.

Comment: Hi Loa, thanks for your suggestion.
I updated to JDK8 and the problem was fixed, however I need to deliver the project on JDK7, I found a solution to the problem and I thought I would share it with you if you are interested.

In your start() method simply load the stylesheet manually using root.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("view/MainView.css").toExternalForm()); Where root is the name of your FXMLLoader :)

Comment: Oh, thanks for sharing this, I will define your question as one of my favorites. Glad to have helped you a little. I hope you can finish your project. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when opening the Scene Builder.

Installed jdk1.8, set it as my system's default (in /usr/lib/jvm/default-java) and modified my $PATH, none of which seemed to help.

Then updated the Scene Builder from 1.1 to 2.0, linked the 1.1 binary to the 2.0 version ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22333225/1201863)) and finally set the new Scene Builder path in Netbeans -> tools -> options -> Java -> JavaFX, which resolved the issue. Updating the default jdk version may or may not have had something to do with it.

The project itself used jdk1.8 already and I had no trouble running it; I only had issues opening them in the Scene Builder (got that error mentioned in the question title).