# How to use the CSS file in JavaFX project?

Tags: css, javafx

i'm trying to build a `JavaFX Application` and i want to attach the `CSS file` in the `FXML file` but when i try to run the app i get a problem like: `Property "stylesheets" does not exist or is read-only.` in the console i don't know what is the problem exactly (note if i delete the CSS file everything works fine).
The CSS file "csstyle.css" contains:

```
/*
 * Empty Stylesheet file.
 */

 .mainFxmlClass {
  -fx-background-color: blue;
  }
```

Also i wrote in the `Stylesheet` in the `FXML file` the name of the `CSS file` also in the `Style Class` : `.mainFxmlClass` .
So i want to know the error please help me and thanks :)

Comment: And the FXML file looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

The first one is already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21649779/javafx-css-error-property-stylesheets-does-not-exist). Remove

```
stylesheets="@csstyle.css"
```

and add it right after the `<children>` tags of your root container. Since you don't show how is your FXML file, this is how it should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>

<AnchorPane styleClass="mainFxmlClass" ...>
   <children>
         ...
   </children>
   <stylesheets>
      <URL value="@cssstyle.css" />
   </stylesheets>
</AnchorPane>
```

The second is this one:

```
styleClass=".mainFxmlClass"
```

Remove the dot:

```
styleClass="mainFxmlClass"
```

**EDIT**

Given these solutions didn't work and the fact that the OP is using JDK 7 with JavaFX 2.0 these other solutions may help:

Replace:

```
styleClass="mainFxmlClass"
```

with:

```
<styleClass>
    <String fx:value="mainFxmlClass"/>
</styleClass>
```

So your FXML will be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>

<AnchorPane ...>
   <children>
         ...
   </children>
   <styleClass>
       <String fx:value="mainFxmlClass"/>
   </styleClass> 
   <stylesheets>
      <URL value="@cssstyle.css" />
   </stylesheets>
</AnchorPane>
```

And try it again.

Finally, if it is not working, remove the `<stylesheets>` tags, and set the stylesheet file on your Scene:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("cssstyle.css").toExternalForm());
```

So your FXML will be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>

<AnchorPane ...>
   <children>
         ...
   </children>
   <styleClass>
       <String fx:value="mainFxmlClass"/>
   </styleClass>
</AnchorPane>
```

It's really advisable updating JavaFX to newer versions (2.2.45 is the last one for Java 7), and benefit from many new features added.

Comment: How to write the stylesheets inside the children ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant after the root children tags. I've edited my question with a generic FXML file.

Comment: Sorry @José Pereda , the problem still exist !! in the FXML file works fine the design has changed but while running it still: `Property "stylesheets" does not exist or is read-only.` in the console .

Comment: Please post your FXML file so we can see what may be happening, and your JDK version

Comment: Have you cleaned and built the project again?

Comment: What JDK version are you using? And what JavaFX version? Those problems may be related to old versions

Comment: I doubt that with JDK7 you have JavaFX8.. Please check the `javafx.properties` file located in your $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib directory

Comment: JDK 1.7 and  JavaFX 2.0 really i'm sure !

Comment: You didn't say that on your previous comment... I'll update my answer.

Comment: Forgot to notice you, but I've edited my answer a while ago. Let me know if it helps

Comment: oohhhh ! the problem still in the two ways couldn't solve :( please can you explain more ? and big thanks.

Comment: Could you explain that? Have you moved stylesheets to the scene (code) and removed from the FXML?

Comment: yes i did i'm sure i'll explain:  the FXML file shows everything is ok and the background color changed to "blue" like the class wrote in CSS file but while running the application the console says : `Property "stylesheets" does not exist or is read-only.` i don't know what's the problem exactly

Comment: I've edited again my answer, since I think you missed the last part of it: in JavaFX 2.0 there was no `<stylesheets>` tag for FXML, so you have to *remove it* from the FXML file and add it from code (`scene.getStylesheets().add(...)`)