# JavaFx with swing and Java 7

Tags: swing, javafx, java-7

I have a swing application that in a couple of windows I use JavaFX scene to display the content. I deploy my application using Web Start to my clients. If a the client has Java 8 installed on their machine everything is fine but if they have Java 7 installed then the application shuts down as soon as the first JavaFX window appears. The even more weird thinks is that is I have Java Console to open with the application then everything works fine.???

What is there in the Java Console that is helping the application to overcome whatever is the problem?

I have follow the tips here [JavaFX CSS Error ( Property Stylesheets does not exist )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21649779/javafx-css-error-property-stylesheets-does-not-exist) and I also followed the jnlp instructions here http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deploy_swing_apps.htm#BACFDACD
Both helped with other issues I had.

My application has many swing windows that I slowly want to migrate to JavaFX so for a while I want both technologies to be able to run. The fact that when console is showing is making the application run with no problems tells me that there is probably a settings or something that I am missing that could solve my problem.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I advise deploying as a self-contained application rather than a web start application, then the version of Java installed on the target machine doesn't matter.  The question as it is currently asked, may not be answerable.  There are numerous reasons why your application could fail.  One example would be if you packaged the JavaFX jar (jfxrt.jar) with your application, that would cause the application to fail as the jar is tied to specific versions of native libraries which are shipped with a given Java runtime.

Comment: Afair the console side-effect was a Java bug with a specific version, I think it was 7u25. But anyway, if possible for you I rather suggest you enforce Java 8 for your application. Java 7 has long reached its end of life and there are JavaFX bugs that are already fixed in 8 which you don't want to fix or write workarounds. I'm forced to stick with Java 7 (eg because of Solaris support) for now and I gave up on JavaFX for Java 7. However I keep the code in a way that migration from Swing to JavaFX is easy once Java 8 is the way to go (but e. g. there will never be x64 JavaFX for Solaris).