# Using JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0 In NetBeans without admin rights

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder, netbeans-8

I'm looking for a way to use JavaFX Scene Builder without having to install it. (e.g. On a machine I do not have Admin rights to install software on.) To use it as a portable tool, say.

Here is what I did so far:
I used [NetBeans Portable](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nbportable/) and [OpenJDKPortable_7](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openjdkportable/) for Java 7 and added the JavaFX jars' manually after extract them using 7-ZipPortable
When I tried to follow [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/scene-builder-2/work-with-java-ides/sb-with-nb.htm) to embed JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0 In NetBeans I got the following error:

> Selected location does not represent a valid JavaFX Scene Builder installation

When I moved all files in the `javafxfolder` to new folder named `app` then tried to run Scene Builder directly it displays a different error:

> No Main class
>   Fail to lunch JVM

I thought that if I added the config file details it may help a little bit

```
app.mainjar=SceneBuilder.jar
app.version=1.1
app.id=com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder
app.preferences.id=com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder
app.mainclass=com/javafx/main/Main
app.classpath=
jvmarg.1=-Djava.security.manager
jvmarg.2=-Djava.security.policy=$APPDIR/app/scenebuilder.policy
jvmarg.3=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
jvmuserarg.1.name=-Djava.util.logging.config.file=
jvmuserarg.1.value=$APPDIR/app/logging.properties
jvmuserarg.2.name=-Xmx
jvmuserarg.2.value=999m
```

Can someone propose another solution?

Comment: Have a look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143009/javafx-scene-builder-2-0-error-in-netbeans

Comment: @NDY Thanks yes i saw it when i try to follow the proposed link i got the error mentioned in the question. they say that Java8 is fully supported now in NetBean but because I'm using PortableJava i could find java 7

Comment: SceneBuilder 2+ creates GUIs which target a Java 8+ runtime.  I do not recommend trying to use SceneBuilder 2+ with a Java 7 development environment.  I also do not recommend copying JavaFX jars around (there are other parts to the JavaFX system than just jars).  Instead use a Java runtime which already embeds JavaFX (e.g. Oracle Java 8+).

Comment: Perhaps try the [Gluon SceneBuilder build](http://gluonhq.com/gluon-supports-scene-builder/): "The first release is simply a Java jar file which you can run using the normal methods (that is, `java -jar SceneBuilder.jar`)". Of course that assumes a pre-installed Java 8/JavaFX 8 environment.   Also, I don't know if the NetBeans SceneBuilder integration will work with the Gluon SceneBuilder distribution (at least currently) - perhaps ask Gluon about this.

Comment: thank you all for your help I'm on it